# How to maintain multiple localization files in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, localization, xliff

Is there a way to create a xliff file per language that contains ONLY the diff from a certain build, commit, tag etc..?
Or is there a way to let the translator know which strings are to be translated in the xliff file and which are not?
Otherwise sending the complete xliff file to the translator every release can be very costly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong translator. Every professional translator and every professional translation tool out there uses a Translation Memory. It stores everything the translator has ever translated and then translates that automatically. Sometimes the translator still charges a small fee for those matches, but that is normal.
Nevertheless, it should be almost free.